# How do I do multiple things at once in Python (2.7.12) (Threading?)

Tags: python-2.7, python-multithreading

I'm trying to figure out how to load a long python program and make a loading animation run at the same time. I've looked around and found threading, but I haven't been able to find out how to use threading to do this.

Edit: My code https://gyazo.com/adb1f0a77d58ba89c9b133972bc17d03

Comment: Can you show code for your loading animation? It might be helpful in giving you a more specific example than Google can.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coding is blocked on this school computer, so **I haven't seen the coding provided**, but I'll still be able to help.  You can make use of the built-in Python Thread module to do this.

First of all, you would need to put your loading animation in a function.  Have this animation in a while loop that terminates when a variable, lets use *loadingfinished*, is True.

```
def loading_animation():
    global loadingfinished # may or may not be needed
    while not loadingfinished:
        #insert code here
```

Once you create this function, you would set loadingfinished to zero.

Now, after making sure the module "thread" is imported, you would type

```
thread.start_new(loading_animation, ())
```

This starts loading_animation as a new thread, with no arguments.  After this, you would just have your normal code, the stuff that you need to load.

Once you are done with the loading code, you simply set loadingfinished to True!  This is what your code should look like:

```
import thread

def loading_animation():
    global loadingfinished # may or may not be needed
    while not loadingfinished:
        #insert animation code here

loadingfinished = False
thread.start_new(loading_animation, ())

#insert loading code here

loadingfinished = True
#This by itself causes the separate thread to terminate.

#You may want to put a delay of a tenth of a second or so here,
#to make extra sure the other thread is terminated before you continue.
```

Multithreading is a great thing to learn, especially in Python, since it's a slow language.  I usually like separating my blitting and calculations into different threads.  This can almost double your program performance!

You can learn more about the thread module here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#module-thread

I have not been able to test this code, so tell me in the comments below if there are any errors.

Comment: It worked very well, the code was set up to test if it worked so I had to edit it to accommodate threading but now I have this bit of code as an example and can use it to finish this project plus more in the future, thanks for the help!